# is it possible to create a parallel operations inside one partition of spark?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, key-value, rdd

i am new to spark and to its relevant concepts, so please be kind with me and help me to clear up my doubts, i'll give you an example to help you to understand my question.

i have one javaPairRDD "rdd" which contains tuples like

```
Tuple2 <Integer,String[]>
```

lets assume that String[].length =3, means it contains 3 elements besides the key,what i want to do is to update each element of the vector using 3 RDDs and 3 operations,"R1" and "operation1" is used to modify the first element,"R2" and "operation2" is used to modify the second element and "R3" and "operation3" is used to modify the third element,

> R1, R2 and R3 are the RDDs that provide the new values of elements

i know that spark devides the data (in this example is "rdd") into many partitions, but what i am asking about : is it possible to do different operations in the same partition and at the same time?

according to my example,and because i have 3 operations, it means that i can take 3 tuples at the same time instead of taking only one to operate it:

the treatment that i want it is :(t refers the time)

```
at t=0:
*tuple1=use operation1 to modify the element 1 

*tuple2=use operation2 to modify the element2 

*tuple3=use operation3 to modify the element 3
```

at t=1:

```
 *tuple1=use operation2 to modify the element 2 

 *tuple2=use operation3 to modify the element3 

 *tuple3=use operation1 to modify the element 1
```

at t=2:

```
*tuple1=use operation.3 to modify the element 3

*tuple2=use operation1 to modify the element1 

*tuple3=use operation2 to modify the element 2
```

After finish updating the 3 first tuples, i take others (3 tuples) from the same partion to treat them, and so on..

> please be kind it's just a thought that crossed my mind, and i want to know if it is possible to do it or not, thank you for your help

Comment: Take a look at `mapPartitions` - it may help you a bit

Comment: I downvoted because I think you need to take more time to read spark documentation and concepts. In this state, this question barely makes sense imo.

Answer (score 1):

Spark doesn't guarantee the order of execution.

You decide how individual elements of RDD should be transformed and Spark is responsible for applying the transformation to all elements in a way that it decides is the most efficient.

Depending on how many executors (i.e. thread or servers or both) are available in your environment Spark will actually process as many tuples as possible at the same time.

Comment: thank you very much @Tomasz Błachut, i understood very well that all depends on the number of cores (executers), but i was thinking that maybe the same core can treat many tuples at the same time, but after your answers, i think it has no sense, bcz spark already does this

Answer (score 1):

First of all, welcome to the Spark community.

To add to @Tomasz Błachut answer, Spark's execution context does not identify nodes (e.g. one computing PC) as individual processing units but instead their cores. Therefore, one job may be assigned to two cores on a 22-core Xeon instead of the whole node.

Spark EC does consider nodes as computing units when it comes to their efficiency and performance, though; as this is relevant for dividing bigger jobs among nodes of varying performance or blacklisting them if they are slow or fail often.

Comment: thank you very much  @sebszyller, i understood very well that all depends on the number of cores (executers), but i was thinking that maybe the same core can treat many tuples at the same time, but after your answers, i think it has no sense, bcz spark already does this.